# Passing arguments doesn't work in git bash, but it works in Windows cmd

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments, git-bash

```
$ python testsuit_adaptation.py ../testsuits /api
['testsuit_adaptation.py', '../testsuits', 'C:/Program Files/Git/api']
below testcase need to do adaptation
```

Pass 3 paras in CLI, in last para, it will be appened one post-fix of "C:/Program Files/Git".

But when get this value from `sys.argv`
"/api" to "c:/Program Files/Git/api"
even I use quotation mark to mark it, it doesn't work.

```
$ python testsuit_adaptation.py ../testsuits "/api"
['testsuit_adaptation.py', '../testsuits', 'C:/Program Files/Git/api']
below testcase need to do adaptation
```

But it works in cmd of Windows.

```
C:\My_Space\Codes\my_codes\Python\sct_scenario\utils>python testsuit_adaptation.py ../testsuits /api
['testsuit_adaptation.py', '../testsuits', '/api']
below testcase need to do adaptation
```

Comment: Conversion of anything that looks like it might be a path to Windows form is a "Git Bash"/msys2 thing not a general bash thing. Use Linux and it won't happen.

Answer (score 2):

To turn this off, run:

```
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1
```

To turn the default behavior back on:

```
unset MSYS_NO_PATHCONV
```

Comment: it works, thanks , by the way, how you know it. because i try to google it, and don't find answers

Comment: @alajl, I specifically used the search terms `"git bash" suppress path conversion`. If that hadn't worked I would have changed `"git bash"` to `msys2`, but it found adequate results as it was.